# Why my computer's HDMI port doesn't transmit anything?

Tags: hdmi

I have a laptop computer with HDMI output port, a tv monitor with HDMI input. So i've a cable formerly used with good success. Now if I bind computer and monitor with that cable nothing appears on my tv but "No signal detected".

Why my computer's HDMI port doesn't transmit anything?

Comment: What operating system are you using? what have you tried so far? if on a windows system, have you tried to `WIN+P` ?

Comment: Resolved, as suggested using `Win+P`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments, `WIN+P` key combination and selecting the proper video output solves this issue.